# CSV Export/Import in drupal

Tags: csv, drupal

hi all i am getting  a probelm in **csv** export download in **drupal**  the  **csv report file** *first 75 records are getting empty* and after the empty rows *we are getting actual report*

How to remove those empty rows in CSV file?

Comment: How are you doing those exports?

Comment: Maybe you was testing webform, i.e. entered no values. Are those records also empty in back-end? If so, you can delete them.

Comment: Hmm....hard to say. If you are sure that there is a bug you should consider reporting it. Anyway, even making CSV export manually, on your own shouldn't be big problem.

Comment: Remove line breaks before DocType in HTML source code

Comment: I am getting the white space problem before doc type declaration how i can sole this issue please help me because of this spaces i get the problem in webform report

Thanks&Reg.
praveen
praveen.544@gmail.com